# Unable to render second react component

Tags: reactjs

I am just fiddling with react to make a simple website. So here's the code

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.3.js"></script>
  <!-- In-browser JSX transformer, remove when pre-compiling JSX. -->
  <script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/jsx">

    var Header = React.createClass({
        render: function(){

            return (<div >
                    <div className="page-header">
                        <h1>{this.props.big} <small>{this.props.small}</small></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>);
        }
    });

var options = {
    big: "React.js is awesome",
    small: "It's strict"
};


var headerComponent = React.createElement(Header, options);
React.render(headerComponent, document.querySelector('.container'));

</script>
```

This works fine. When ever I try to add a new component, there would be a parsing error at line 39. I don't understand why

Here's my added component code

```
<script type="text/jsx">
    var Vamsi = React.createClass({
        render: function(){
            return ({
                    <div> 
                        Hi 
                    </div>
            });
        };
    });

    var Header = React.createClass({
        render: function(){

            return (<div >

                    <div className="page-header">
                        <h1>{this.props.big} <small>{this.props.small}</small></h1>
                    </div>
                    <Vamsi />

                </div>);
        }
    });

var options = {
    big: "React.js is awesome",
    small: "It's strict"
};


var headerComponent = React.createElement(Header, options);
React.render(headerComponent, document.querySelector('.container'));

</script>
</html>
```

ps: I added a component called Vamsi, and I'm getting parse error un expected token at line 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra braces that are not required `{ }` in the return method which would be considered as an object. The method requires you to return a method and not an object. Also createClass takes objects so each method should be separated by a comma.

```
var Vamsi = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (<div> 
                    Hi 
                </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes it's working, Why that was a problem? can you explain?

Comment: you have extra flower brackets in return method

Comment: I understood, it won't treat that as object? {}

Comment: the render method requires a method and not an object. So you HAVE to return a method. Also, the object you are trying to return is not valid